# Getting a Huawei E3327 USB 4G modem to work with Raspberry Pi 4 running DietPi (Debian)

Tags: networking, huawei

I want a Huawei E3327 to work as a fallback on a Raspberry Pi 4B.
The modem shows constant cyan light, which means that there es a 4G connection established (I previously configured APN using a windows machine).

I successfully used usb_modeswitch to switch the modem in the right state, and a a new network interface `eth1` shows up.

I configured a static IP, my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
# Drop-in configs
source interfaces.d/*

# Ethernet
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1

# WiFi
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
wireless-power off
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

# hotspot
iface wlan1 inet static
address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.42.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.42.1

#HUAWEI E3372
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.8.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.8.0
broadcast 192.168.8.255
```

There is also the internal WiFi connection of the RasPi and an external USB WiFi dongle configured as a hotspot, which works.

The problem: I can only `ping 8.8.8.8` when there is a wifi connection. The huawei modem does not seem to work.
Without the wifi connection I get `Network is unreachable` when I try `ping 8.8.8.8`

with established wifi connection, `ip address` shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:01:c0:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:3a:dd:01:c0:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.136/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 603872sec preferred_lft 603872sec
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2312 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:60:f9:64:4f:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.100/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I make the modem work and act as a fallback when there is no WiFi connection?

Comment: hm, why the static IP?

Comment: I got that from a blog post. I fist tried to set the static IP to 192.168.42.100 to have it in the same net as the access point, but that did not work either. I also tried dhcp an the modem. It got an address, but also "network is unreachable"

Comment: stick with DHCP. The modem needs to be the one that tells your RPi which network and gateway to use, so that it knows to forward packets to you.